# Add price rule for every other product in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, rule

I've been searching for the option to do price ruling in Prestashop this way:

1st item of product costs $10, every other costs $8.

I can't seem to find it and wonder if I can hack prestashop in any way to achieve this.

There are options to to include percentage and fixed amount discount however this does not work the way our marketing works. Thanks for your input !

Please note I googled this online as well and didn't find relevant solution. If it does not belong to stackoverflow, I apologize.

I've seen some modules for this ranging from 50 to 200 EUR, and I wonder if there is simple, maybe even free solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try: `Catalog->Choose product->Prices tab->Add a new specific price->Starting at 2 unit->And add new price`. But in this way 1 and 2 item would have a new price. Not only second product.

Comment: Hi, thx for a tip, i've seen that, however that doesn't achieve the effect and I'll loose around 10 EUR on each order this way.